# Interactive graphical data input in R

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to do interactive and graphical user data input with R?`

I have a time vector `t<-1:100` and I would like the user to supply graphically values of `y`.

Ideally I would like the interface to start with `y<-rep(0, length(t))` have a do a `plot(t,y, ylim=c(0,50), type="h")` and I would like the user to draw at each t the height of `y`.

then use the graphically user supplied `y` vector to do some calculations.

Is this possible with R or should I turn to javascript? Can Shiny do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this natively in R (without opening Shiny, etc.) you can use the `locator` function, which will record the position of the mouse when clicking on the graphics device. Its first argument accepts a number of positions/clicks to record.

Here's a trivial example that updates your plot after each click:

```
t <- 1:5
y <- rep(0, length(t))
plot(t,y, ylim=c(0,50), type="h")
for(i in seq_along(t)){
    y[i] <- locator(1)$y
    plot(t,y, ylim=c(0,50), type="h")
}
```